# string.find(" ") is not finding spaces

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to find space in a string that a user inputs. I want to use `find()` from `std::string` to return the position of the space.

If the input is "Seattle, WA USA", and I want `find(" ", 0)` to return `8`, how would I do this? 8th is the space after ","

```
string inputString = " ";
cout << "Enter String to modify" << endl;
cin >> inputString;
int spac = inputString.find(" " , 0);
```

But `find()` is keep returning `0`.
I am not sure why.

Comment: Note that `0` means the _first character_ and does not indicate a failure to find: `std::string::npos` indicates not found.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not reading the space (`cin >> inputString` stops on whitespace...).

Use `std::getline(std::cin, inputString)` instead.

Comment: Thank you, and what does this "getline" do?

Comment: @SndLt, see the reference page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `cin` which truncates words after first space and store it to `inputString`:

```
string inputString;

getline(cin, inputString);

int spac = inputString.find(" " , 0);

cout << spac << endl;
```