# Trouble finding 'space' character in string

Tags: c++, string

I have been struggling to get a simple function to work, the purpose is to pass in a character, the function then search's the ALPHABET string and then if the character is found, returns the index of the character within the string .

I have a basic constant containing the alphabet, including an apostrophe and space character:

```
const string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,’ ";
```

Now I have a function which takes a character as an argument:

```
int charaPosition(string chara){

    transform(chara.begin(), chara.end(),chara.begin(), ::toupper);

    int charaIndex = ALPHABET.find(chara, 0);

    if (charaIndex != string::npos) {

        return charaIndex;

    }else{
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
   }
}
```

Function is initiated like so:

```
cout << charaPosition("s") << endl;
```

It all works fine up to a certain point, if I pass in A, the function returns 0, B return 1 etc. However if I pass in the space character, it returns 31 rather than 29, and if I pass in the apostrophe character, it just doesn't get found.

I would be very grateful for anyones help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475744/string-find-is-not-finding-spaces <- this is the same question, I believe.

Comment: Having a [mcve] that we could simply copy and paste into an IDE would be great...

Comment: Try using 7 bit ascii apostrophe `'` instead of `´`

Comment: space character is (char)32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `’` is not ASCII, it's Unicode. It occupies more than 1 byte in your string.

1. `It all works fine up to a certain point, if I pass in A, the function returns 0, B return 1 etc`: Right, up to that point, it's all ASCII, so you have 1 byte per character, therefore all resulting indices make sense;
2. `However if I pass in the space character, it returns 31 rather than 29`: The problem is that `’` occupies exactly 3 bytes (226 128 153) rather than 1 byte, because it's Unicode. You should use `std::wstring` and `wchar_t` to make this work properly, or replace that character by `'` (ASCII 39);
3. `and if I pass in the apostrophe character, it just doesn't get found.`: That *apostrophe* is not ASCII, so you're searching for multiple bytes instead of a single one.

Comment: Is there an automatic conversion of a Unicode character to its UTF-8 encoded format to be saved in std::string?

Comment: I'm asking this because in **const string ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,’ "**, how can the apostrophe occupy 3 bytes if there is no automatic conversion of its Unicode code point to UTF-8 before it is stored in std::string.

Comment: One more thing, how come UTF-8 "can't represent all Unicode characters". To my knowledge this encoding can represent all Unicode characters using 1-4 bytes.(In fact it can also represent characters with more than 21 significant bits,if there are any, using 5 or 6 bytes but i think the standard doesn't allow that because a Unicode character's code point can't be represented by more than 21 bits)

Comment: You're right. I'm wrong on the `UTF-8 can't represent all characters Unicode can`, it's a fact it can. I just wrote garbage. To answer your question, string literals in C++ accept unicode without warnings, and therefore `std::string` which have a constructor that receives a `const char *` will not be able to tell you anything about this, it will just assume you have done the right thing in the first place. The compiler does not convert anything, it just accepts what you typed there.