# How to get substring after a whitespace?

Tags: c++, string, substring

According to: [C++ How to get substring after a character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163723/c-how-to-get-substring-after-a-character)

```
x.substr(x.find(":") + 1);
```

How can I do the same, but with whitespace ? because `find()` ignores spaces.

Comment: What have you tried to solve your homework?

Comment: @Vettel: "*`find()` ignores spaces*" - no, it doesn't. `x.substr(x.find(" ") + 1);` works just fine. Also `x.find(' ')` works, too

Comment: The `find` member function does **not** ignore the whitespace.

Comment: @MayankJain: "*Stringstream let you specify delimiters*" - no, it doesn't.  You might be thinking of `std::getline()` instead, which has an optional delimiter, and can use a stringstream as input.

Comment: You should take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475744/string-find-is-not-finding-spaces)

Comment: @vettelsebastian why dont you just try it and see what happens? find(" ")

Comment: @EugeneSh.: the problem with that question is that the user wasn't reading strings with spaces in them to begin with.  That was a problem with using `cin >> ...` to read strings, not with using `find()` to find space characters.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes. So I would imagine the OP has a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want white space you need to use `find_if()` with an appropriate lambda that calls `is::space()`

```
auto pos = find_if(std::begin(x), std::end(x), [](unsigned char c){return std::isspace(c);});
pos++;
for(;pos!=x.end();pos++)
cout << *pos;
```

Comment: Please clarify yourself. Which other character?   `Ascii` value of `whitespace` is 32

Comment: That is the character space. ASCII 32. "White Space" is a couple of other characters including tab. See the defintion of `isSpace()` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace

Comment: Ooo, Thanks now i undersand.

Comment: Thanks but it gives me error to "pos" in the substr function : https://imgur.com/a/guuDP

Comment: pos is `string::iterator`